# Git Branch develop and master have diverged

Tags: git, github, merge

I am following a git flow model with my branches, and thus have a develop and master branch, which originally were in sync.

My process is create a feature branch from develop, merge it into develop when done with the feature, create a release branch, apply any fixes and when tested fully, merge the release branch back first into the develop branch and then into master.

So they should have been in sync, but apparently have diverged, because every time I merge the release branch into master I am getting merge errors where its asking me to resolve them manually.

My question is, is it a good idea to overwrite the master branch completely with the develop branch and thus start fresh, which I can afford to do at this point in time, or is there another solution to this type of problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not able to cleanly merge `develop` into `master` then there has to be *something* in `master` that's not in `develop`. You certainly could just declare bankruptcy and `push --force` `develop` to replace `master`, but I would personally be wary of losing something important that just never found its way into `master`.

After a successful merge of `develop` into `master`, does `git diff master develop` show anything interesting?

Comment: There are some differences in that there are some files that were deleted from develop that didnt get deleted in master, but these are insignificant, and other than that there isn't really anything major, just 1 or 2 other minor differences in files that aren't really important.  So would you suggest I just overwrite master with develop ?

Comment: If you don't need the trivial differences in `master`, I would indeed just `git push -f origin develop:master` and keep your history simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems since you don't mind blowing away your changes in master that are not in develop, you should just overwrite master with develop; going forward, according to your flow you should never be making commits to master, only branch off of develop, then merge into develop, and once in a while merge develop into master when you are sure your build is clean